# How to show datalist in datalist itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, webforms, datalist, listcontrol

Here's the problem I'm having in my ASP.NET web-form project.

I have Datalist which shows all Products from Database , Each product have one or more colors . 
At the moment i write queries like this in order to  show all product and default photo of that but not colors related to that product :

```
var query = from p in db.Products
                        from c in db.Pics
                        where c.ProductId == p.ProductId
                        where c.IsDefault == true
                        select new { p.ProductId, p.ProductType, p.Name, p.Number, p.Package, p.Model, p.Size, p.Material, p.MantoLengh, c.PicAddress};

            DataList1.DataSource = query;
            DataList1.DataBind();
```

I don't know how to bind related colors to a list-control ( like datalist or other list-Controls) inside of my DataList control, here is a view of my database diagram for more information :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query would work though I apologise in advance if my syntax is slightly out, am more VB than C#...

```
        var query = from p in db.Products 
                    select new { p.ProductId, 
                        p.ProductType, 
                        p.Name, 
                        p.Number, 
                        p.Package, 
                        p.Model, 
                        p.Size, 
                        p.Material, 
                        p.MantoLengh, 
                        p.Pics.Where(x => x.IsDefault).Select(x => x.PicAddress).ToList(), 
                        p.Colors.Select(x => x.ColorHex).ToList() };
```

Basically, in the anonymouse type you select you can use lambda to fetch the one-to-many collections using Select().ToList(), and use .Where() to perform filtering.

Hope that helps.

EDIT - In response to your comment:

I chose the hex colour strings because they looked like the best bet for creating the actual colours.  To cerate a colour from Hex, see [this article](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/18f13f1e-853e-4ea8-9ea4-5113357f9397/Convert-Hex-String-to-dotnet-Color.aspx).  Where on the list do you want to add the colours?

Comment: Then how to bind colors to a list-controls ?

Comment: @Mostafa: I've added a link to show how to create colours from Hex Strings.  I don't know where you want to apply the colour on the list boxes, but hopefully that'll get you started

Answer (score 0):

I believe that after you have bound the results to your datalist, you should be able to do something like this in your DataList

$<%#query.DataItem("Colors")%>